# Statistical function in C#

Tags: c#

I am doing some work in C# to calculate the binomial probability density function of some variables. Just wandering is there any package I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always interop into a C/C++ library *or* (better yet) create a light C++ .NET wrapper in your solution that interops with such a library. Then you're able to use something like the [GNU scientific library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/). There will always be much more to choose from there.

EDIT: With "choose from there" I'm referring to the C/C++ "world" as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Math.net](http://www.mathdotnet.com/)